# SQL MERGE Conditional Delete on MATCH

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2015

I have two tables that I use to `merge`. Something is wrong with my query and I cannot find any information as to why. What happens is; I will run the query and it works fine as my target table populates with the information I want. I then run the query again (immediately after) and it changes (38 rows affected) I run it again and it adds the rows back in - and again... rows are deleted. There are over 100 rows but only the same rows seem to be affected. Nothing changes in the source table.

I suspect that I am performing a `DELETE` on `WHEN MATCHED` - I can only find information for `DELETE WHEN NOT MATCHED` - but I don't know as this only seems to affect the same 38 rows every time.

The tables and (hopefully) information you need are here in my code:

```
MERGE QA.dbo.RMA AS target USING Touchstn02.dbo.RMA_Detail AS source 
ON (target.RMANUM_52 = source.RMANUM_52) 
WHEN MATCHED AND (source.STATUS_52 >3) 
THEN
DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND (source.STATUS_52 < 4) AND (source.RECQTY_52 > 0) 
THEN
INSERT         (RMANUM_52, RMADATE_52, CUSTID_52, RETNUM_52, RETQTY_52, 
                SERIAL_52, REPAIR_52, 
                RPLACE_52, CREDIT_52, WRKNUM_52, KEYWRD_52, RECQTY_52, 
                RECDTE_52, STATUS_52, 
                REM1_52, REM2_52, REM3_52, Comment, CMPDTE)
VALUES        (source.RMANUM_52, source.RMADTE_52, source.CUSTID_52, 
               source.RETNUM_52, 
               source.RETQTY_52, source.SERIAL_52, source.REPAIR_52, 
               source.RPLACE_52, source.CREDIT_52, 
               source.WRKNUM_52, source.KEYWRD_52, source.RECQTY_52, 
               source.RECDTE_52, 
               source.STATUS_52, source.REM1_52, source.REM2_52, 
               source.REM3_52, source.REM4_52, 
               source.CMPDTE_52);
```

As always, I appreciate any help/input

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table which updates the STATUS_52 when you're inserting? Edit: We may need more information as to what records are being affected incorrectly.

Comment: there is no trigger on either table

Comment: after looking at the records at the suggestion of @justiceorjustus, i noticed it is always the last 38 rows affected the upper (64) rows are never affected - does this information help?

Comment: What is the value of `RMANUM_52` and `STATUS_52` in the rows that are affected?

Comment: @TabAlleman And the rows that are not affected. Also, have you tried switching your `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED`?

Comment: RMANUM_52| --- STATUS_52
 
80002576| 2
80002594| 3
80002594| 3
80002594| 3
80002594| 2
80002594| 2
80002594| 2
80002594| 2
80002602| 3
80002609| 1
80002629| 2
80002764| 2
80002764| 2
80002764| 1
80002772| 2
80002772| 2
80002772| 2
80002772| 2
80002793| 2
80002798| 2
80002808| 2
80002808| 2
80002808| 2
80002810| 2
80002823| 2
80002825| 2
80002825| 2
80002833| 2
80002861| 2
80002861| 2
80002861| 2
80002861| 2
80002861| 2
80002882| 1
80002882| 1
80002882| 1
80002917| 1
80002955| 1

Comment: Is `RMANUM_52` a unique key in both tables, or can this column contain duplicate values?

Comment: Can you run select statement first? select on match and source.STATUS_52 >3, another select NOT MATCHED AND (source.STATUS_52 < 4) AND (source.RECQTY_52 > 0). Any conflicting result?

Comment: RMANUM_52 can (and does) contain duplicate values

Comment: sorry @Wendy, I am not sure I understand how to do what you are asking. please forgive my ignorance - I'm new at this

Comment: As general rule during creating coding, always run select statement before update/delete, so you can check what will be deleted/updated.

Comment: @Wendy, understood and thank you for the advice. I simply do not understand how to use a select statement in a merge. can you share a link that would point me in that direction? I googled it and came up short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got it!

The 38 rows being deleted have at least two STATUS_52 values in the source table for these RMANUM_52 key values.

For a given RMANUM_52 key value:

- One of the STATUS_52 values will be < 4 and have a Qty > 0.
- The other row Status value will be > 3.

So, on the first run through, a row is inserted with a STATUS_52 value < 4.

Then on next run through the DELETE is triggered because the matching is by RMANUM_52 and the STATUS_52 in the SOURCE table.  The tricky thing here is that we are looking back for status values into all rows in the source table (including rows that were not part of the first insert).  And there is a different row in the source table that matches RMANUM_52 with a STATUS_52 > 3.  So DELETE logic matches and delete happens.

I can't tell from your example exactly what your requirements are so I'm not going to hazard guessing a fix.

Comment: you got me on the right track - thanks @David Coster! The actual issue is RMANUM_52 is not unique (there is not a unique identifier in the table) so, I ended up looking at two different columns. Thanks again - I thought everybody gave up!

Comment: I'm really glad I could offer some help :-)